# Retorno de um único elemento de uma lista em uma LINQ

Tags: array, lista, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou pegando elementos de uma lista e não posso apagar os elementos, tenho que retornar todos eles. Encontrei um problema no final desta query, onde tem o comentário

```
    //Erro
 tagItems.AddElementsTo(this.TagItems);
```

E acontece este erro 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o código de todo o método para poderem analisar.

```
public void Initialize(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher dispatcher)
        {
            var logbookDisposable = default(IDisposable);
            var tagsDisposable = default(IDisposable);
            var tagValuesDisposable = default(IDisposable);

            var clockDisposable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
                .StartWith(-1L)
                .SubscribeOn(dispatcher)
                .Synchronize()
                .Subscribe(_ => DateTime = DateTime.Now);

            var mainDisposable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
                .StartWith(-1L)
                .SubscribeOn(dispatcher)
                .SelectMany(async _ =>
                {
                    this.TagItems = new ObservableCollection<TagItem>();
                    var subscriptions = await GetSubscriptionsAsync();

                    return subscriptions;

                })
                .SelectMany(subs => subs)
                .Subscribe(sub =>
                {
                    var info = sub.info;
                    var tags = sub.tags;

                    logbookDisposable?.Dispose();
                    logbookDisposable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
                        .StartWith(-1L)
                        .SubscribeOn(dispatcher)
                        .Synchronize()
                        .SelectMany(async _ => await GetLogbookItems(info))
                        .SubscribeOn(dispatcher)
                        .Synchronize()
                        .Subscribe(logbookItems =>
                        {
                            this.LogbookItems = logbookItems.ToObservableCollection();
                        });

                    tagsDisposable?.Dispose();
                    tagsDisposable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
                        .StartWith(-1L)
                        .SubscribeOn(dispatcher)
                        .Synchronize()
                        .SelectMany(async _ => await GetTagItems(tags))
                        .SubscribeOn(dispatcher)
                        .Synchronize()
                        .Subscribe(tagItems =>
                        {

                            //Erro
                            tagItems.AddElementsTo(this.TagItems);


                            tagValuesDisposable?.Dispose();
                            tagValuesDisposable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
                                .SelectMany(async _ => await GetTagValues((from ti in tagItems select ti.ID).ToArray()))
                                .SubscribeOn(dispatcher)
                                .Synchronize()
                                .Subscribe(tagValues =>
                                {
                                    var query = (from ti in tagItems
                                                 join tv in tagValues on ti.ID equals tv.TagID
                                                 select new { ti, tv }).ToArray();

                                    foreach (var item in query)
                                    {
                                        item.ti.Value = item.tv.Value;
                                    }
                                });
                        });
                });

            var disposable = new Core.Utils.DisposeInvoker(() =>
            {
                clockDisposable?.Dispose();
                mainDisposable?.Dispose();
                logbookDisposable?.Dispose();
                tagsDisposable?.Dispose();
                tagValuesDisposable?.Dispose();
            });

            disposables.Add(disposable);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Qual o problema?

Em código multilinear(multithread) as coleções devem possuir sincronização de acesso aos dados para que chamadas de dois ou mais threads concorrentes não fiquem em situação de impasse ao decidir quem irá obter primeiro acesso os dados e por consequência congelem o sistema.

## Qual a solução?

A mensagem de erro está informando-lhe que a coleção em questão [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) não suporta que um thread diferente do que o criou modifique seus dados.

A solução é trocar `ObservableCollection<T>` por uma classe que suporte chamadas multilineares. No .NET Framework não existe uma classe `ObservableCollection<T>` então para solucionar o problema você vai ter que criar uma classe que irá interceptar o evento ['OnCollectionChanged'](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) e ao invés de conceder a alteração convencional dos elementos da coleção, essa classe ela irá despachar invocações aos métodos necessários para a alteração on fly(sincronizadas pelo sistema) dos elementos da coleção.

```
public class MyTObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = this.CollectionChanged;
            if (CollectionChanged != null)
                foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    DispatcherObject dispObj = nh.Target as DispatcherObject;
                    if (dispObj != null)
                    {
                        Dispatcher dispatcher = dispObj.Dispatcher;
                        if (dispatcher != null && !dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                        {
                            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                                (Action)(() => nh.Invoke(this,
                                    new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))),
                                DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    nh.Invoke(this, e);
                }
        }
    }
```

Então é só trocar as classes de objetos `ObservableCollection<T>` para `MyTObservableCollection<T>`.

**Nota:**
 Essa classe `MyTObservableCollection<T>` em aspecto global ela continua insegura com relação ao escopo multilinear(thread unsafe) porém resolve o seu problema. Caso ocorra futuramente erro similar como outro tipo de operação você deverá extender o mesmo raciocínio para tal operação. Se você extender esse raciocínio, converter as chamadas de lineares para invocações on fly, para toda a classe esta classe se torna segura em relação ao escopo multilinear(thread safe).